# Matrix Form Representation of Results

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have 7 csv files which has list of words. I have taken all the words from 7 csv and put in a new file called Total_Words_list.

The issue is that I need an output in the following matrix:

```
   APPLE BALL CAT DOG....
A    0    1    1   0
B    1    1    0   1
C    1    1    1   0
```

Here the words from the main list forms the rows and the 7 file names form the column. If a word is present in file A it turns 1 else 0, and so on. This goes on for all 7 csv files in a single run and i get the above result.

I am not sure how to approach the issue.

Comment: What is content of `Total_Words_list` ?

Comment: It is the collection of all words from the 7 csv like a Master Data File.

Comment: And what is format? Please add 2 - 3 rows.

Comment: There is no format, just a list of words in .csv format.

Comment: Ok, so each row means one file? So there is 7 rows?

Comment: Yes. And the the total words form the column as I have shown above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for concating all `DataFrames` and then [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html). Last need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by index (`level=0`) with aggregating [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

temp=u"""CAT;BALL
"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=None, header=None)

print (df1)

temp=u"""DOG;BALL;APPLE
"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=None, header=None)

print (df2)


temp=u"""DOG;BALL;APPLE;CAT
"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df3 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=None, header=None)

print (df3)

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], keys=['A','B','C'])
df.reset_index(1, drop=True, inplace=True)
print (df)
     0     1      2    3
A  CAT  BALL    NaN  NaN
B  DOG  BALL  APPLE  NaN
C  DOG  BALL  APPLE  CAT
```

```
print (df.stack().reset_index(1, drop=True).str.get_dummies())
   APPLE  BALL  CAT  DOG
A      0     0    1    0
A      0     1    0    0
B      0     0    0    1
B      0     1    0    0
B      1     0    0    0
C      0     0    0    1
C      0     1    0    0
C      1     0    0    0
C      0     0    1    0

print (df.stack().reset_index(1, drop=True).str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum())
   APPLE  BALL  CAT  DOG
A      0     1    1    0
B      1     1    0    1
C      1     1    1    1
```

---

Another solution with [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns (`level=0`, axis=1) with aggregating [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
print (pd.get_dummies(df, dummy_na=False, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum())

   APPLE  BALL  CAT  DOG
A      0     1    1    0
B      1     1    0    1
C      1     1    1    1
```

EDIT by comment:

Another approach is get `dummies` from each dataframe separately and then `concat` output:

```
df11 = pd.get_dummies(df1, dummy_na=False, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
#print (df11)
df21 = pd.get_dummies(df2, dummy_na=False, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
#print (df21)
df31 = pd.get_dummies(df3, dummy_na=False, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
         .groupby(level=0, axis=1).sum()
#print (df31)

df = pd.concat([df11,df21,df31], keys=['A','B','C']).fillna(0).astype(int)
df.reset_index(1, drop=True, inplace=True)
print (df)
   APPLE  BALL  CAT  DOG
A      0     1    1    0
B      1     1    0    1
C      1     1    1    1
```

Comment: What if instead of temp i need to insert the Main_Words_List.csv file, how can that be done?

Comment: No, try instaed `io.StringIO(temp)` use `file1.csv` for creating each `df1`, `df2`, `df3`...

Comment: Got it!! Thanks again!!

Comment: Glad can help you!

Comment: One last doubt how can I transpose the matrix i.e. A,B,C becomes columns and APPLE, BALL, CAT, DOG becomes rows. Thanks again!!

Comment: Thank you for accepting. Add only  [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) -  `print (df.stack().reset_index(1, drop=True).str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum().T)`

Comment: @jezarel..the code works like a charm but when I add all the 7 csv as my requirement and concatenate them, the dataframe has more than 60000 and the code fails to give a output and just stops..kindly help!!!

Comment: more than 60000 words*

Comment: What is size of your RAM?

Comment: 8GB..it's a MAC Desktop with i5 processor